# Sort the output of array with relation model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to get the results of array like:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "Sedan Car"
    "total" => 3089.0
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▶]
  2 => array:2 [▶]
]
```

But unfortunately with my code I'm getting:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "car_id" => 5
    "total" => 3089.0
    "vehicle_class" => array:13 [▼
      "id" => 5
      "type" => "Standard Car"
      "name" => "Sedan Car"
```

My Controller:

```
$target = Invoice::select('car_id')
            ->selectRaw("SUM(total_price) AS total")
            ->with('vehicleClass')
            ->groupBy('car_id')
            ->get()
            ->toArray();

 dd($target);

    $data = \Lava::DataTable();
    $data->addStringColumn('Country')
              ->addNumberColumn('Popularity');
    foreach($target as $row){
        $data->addRow([$row['car_id'], $row['total'] ]);
        $ket["totalTarget"] += $row['total'];
    }
    \Lava::DonutChart('Don', $data, [
                'title' => $balanceT,
                'height' => '300',
                'is3D'   => true,
            ]);
```

Invoice Model:

```
public function vehicleClass()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(VehicleClass::class,'car_id');

}
```

So my question how to take the value of name from relation model and add it to the array and get SUM "total" of total_price column

To make it more clear :

1. Invoice model & table contain [car_id, total_price]
2. vehicleClass model & tablecontains [name, ..etc]

   - The results which I need [name, Sum [total_price] ]
     name = card_id =>  in relation modle

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
$Data = Invoice::select('car_id', 'total')
            ->selectRaw("SUM(total_price) AS total")
            ->with([
                'vehicleClass'=>function($q) {
                    $q->select('id', 'name');
                }
            ])->get();

dd($Data->first()->vehicleClass->name);
```

Fetching data the way you want it directly is not possible as far as my knowledge goes, unless you use Laravel Mutators. Inside `Invoice` append the following:

```
protected $appends = ['car_name', 'total_price'];

public function getCarNameAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->vehicleClass()->select('id', 'name')->first()->name;
}

public function getTotalPriceAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->selectRaw("SUM(total_price) AS total")->where('id', $this->id)->first()->total;
}
```

Then when you want to retrieve the car name, you could do the following:

```
dd($Data->first()->car_name);
dd($Data->first()->total_price);
```

Comment: user8555937 Thank you so much for your effort but it doesn't works coz I need these data for Lava Chart, I added the complete code in the post, thanks again

Comment: Thanks again but unfortunately by this way I will not be able to get name of vehicleClass for every total price, I mean every total price for specific name and then it should enter in foreach :
foreach($target as $row){
        $data->addRow([$row['name'], $row['total'] ]);
        $ket["totalTarget"] += $row['total'];
    }